# host to host translation in linux?

Tags: linux, hosts

In Linux (fedora or cent OS, etc), I want to say if one program tries to download from one url, it goes to my host (my url) instead of what it tries to go. Something like /etc/hosts, but /etc/hosts is host to ip instead.

Thanks!

Comment: Could you please clarify or give a specific example? I can't understand what you are trying to do here.

Comment: Yes. http://something.com/link.zip to http://theother.net/link.zip , I want to convert a global archive to my local archive without changing the requester's code (url). I mean the program wants to go to something.com, but goes to theother.net (translation).

Answer (score 0):

You can install [Dnsmasq](http://www.thekelleys.org.uk/dnsmasq/doc.html). and configure it to override the upstream DNS servers for particular names. There are Dnsmasq packages for almost every Linux distro. See [this blog post](http://chenyufei.info/blog/2011-01-03/use-dnsmasq-to-setup-a-local-dns-server/) for simple instructions on how to set it up. It's easy to do.

For example, you can configure Dnsmasq to override any particular host name, say `cnn.com` so that any program on your computer, or that uses your computer for DNS, will see `bbcnews.com` instead of `cnn.com`.

If your own host names are configured in /etc/hosts, then in `/etc/nsswitch.conf` change the line

```
hosts:          files dns
```

to

```
hosts:          dns files
```

in order to give DNS preference over the `/etc/hosts` configuration.

Comment: Can I use Dnsmasq to redirect from one internet address/host to another internet host which is mine? Not only to local, but my own internet address.

Comment: @MustafaAsghari: I added more explanation to my answer. I hope that helps answer the question better.

Comment: I successfully installed dnsmasq, it works fine, however my efforts to override upstream dns failed. Can you give me the example of configuration (go to bbc.co.uk instead of cnn.com) here, plz?